# Operator > cannolt be applied b/w operands of 'object' and 'int'

Tags: c#, vb.net, object, int

```
    int i_cnt;    
    int i_row;
    i_cnt = 0;
    i_row = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr_ledger in ds_main.Tables["PandL_New"].Rows) {
        if (((dr_ledger[4] == "SALES ACCOUNTS") 
                    || ((dr_ledger[4] == "PURCHASE ACCOUNTS") 
                    || ((dr_ledger[4] == "OPENING STOCK") 
                    || (dr_ledger[4] == "CLOSING STOCK"))))) {
               i_sum = (i_sum++(dr_ledger[(11) + (12)]));
        }
        if ((dr_ledger[4] == "PROFIT & LOSS A/C")) {
            i_row = i_cnt;
        }
        i_cnt = (i_cnt + 1);
    }
    if ((i_sum == 0)) {
        if ((ds_main.Tables["PandL_New"].Rows[i_row][11] + (ds_main.Tables["PandL_New"].Rows[i_row][12] > 0))) {
            ds_main.Tables["PandL_New"].Rows[i_row][4] = "EXCESS of INCOME OVER EXPENDITURE";
        }
        else {
            ds_main.Tables["PandL_New"].Rows[i_row][4] = "EXCESS OF EXPENDITURE OVER INCOME";
        }
    }
```

This are the two errors appearing and not allowing me to compile:

> Line 1;- (i_sum++(dr_ledger[(11) + (12)]));
>
> Line 2;-(ds_main.Tables["PandL_New"].Rows[i_row][12] > 0)))
>
> 1.)Method name expected
>
> 2.)Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'

Originally this was implemented in VB. The code was as follows:

```
For Each dr_ledger In ds_main.Tables("PandL").Rows
    If
        dr_ledger.Item(2).tolower = "SALES ACCOUNTS".ToLower Or
        dr_ledger.Item(2).tolower = "PURCHASE ACCOUNTS".ToLower Or
        dr_ledger.Item(2).tolower = "OPENING STOCK".ToLower Or
        dr_ledger.Item(2).tolower = "CLOSING STOCK".ToLower
    Then
        i_sum = i_sum + dr_ledger.Item(7)
    End If
    If dr_ledger.Item(2).tolower = "PROFIT & LOSS A/C".ToLower
    Then
        i_row = i_cnt
    End
    If i_cnt = i_cnt + 1
        //...
```

Actually ,from converting this code to c#.... the error appears..

Answer (score 0):

As I understand:

```
i_sum = (i_sum+(dr_ledger[(11) + (12)]));
```

...

```
Convert.ToInt32(ds_main.Tables["PandL_New"].Rows[i_row][12]) > 0
```

Comment: @AnieshSunder wich one?

Comment: i_sum = (i_sum+(dr_ledger[(11) + (12)]));

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(ds_main.Tables["PandL_New"].Rows[i_row][12]) > 0

Answer (score 0):

To apply the `>` and `<` operators in C# the object which you are applying them to must implement the IComparable Interface (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx).

By default `object` does not implement this interface, so cannot have the `<`/`>` operators applied. Depending on the type of the object you could cast it to IComparable then apply the `<` or `>` operator.

```
public bool Compare(object a, object b)
{
    var compA = (IComparable)a;
    var compB = (IComparable)b;

    return compA > compB;
}
```

This however will not work (and throw an exception) if a, or b is an object of type which does not implement IComparable.

With your code, I am guessing that the value of `ds_main.Tables["PandL_New"].Rows[i_row][12]` is returning a `DataRow.Item` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z(v=vs.110).aspx) which is an item and not neccecarrally implementing the IComparable interface. If you were to try casting this to IComparable, then applying the `>` operator it should work:

```
((IComparable) ds_main.Tables["PandL_New"].Rows[i_row][12]) > 0
```

With the first issue, what are you expecting `(i_sum++(dr_ledger[(11) + (12)]));` to do? The `++` operator on an int will iterate it (same as saying `i = i + 1`) and will not take any arguments.

Edit: Given the VB now provided, the line:

```
 i_sum = (i_sum++(dr_ledger[(11) + (12)]));
```

Should be replaced with:

```
 i_sum = i_sum + ((int) dr_ledger[7]);
```

---------- Original Answer

If you want to add the value of `dr_ledger[(11) + (12)]` to `i_sum` you want to use the `+=` or `+` operator instead:

```
i_sum+=(dr_ledger[(11) + (12)]);
// or
i_sum = i_sum + (dr_ledger[(11) + (12)]);
```

However here `dr_ledger[(11) + (12)]` will evaluate to `dr_ledger[23]`, so I am not sure why you have the (11) + (12)?